# 16.04 beta -- problems with samba (systemd related) and nautilus (launcher related)

Tags: unity, nautilus, samba, upstart, 16.04

I decided to take the plunge on doing a `do-release-upgrade` tonight from 14.04.4 to 16.04.

I only have two outstanding issues, both of which might just be due to buggy beta packages but I thought I'd check if anyone else was experiencing them too:

1. Samba doesn't seem to want to get along with systemd;
   installing it and its winbind dependencies leads to a bunch of error
   messages about upstart. Unless there's a new samba package I'm not
   aware of, I'm just assuming it isn't compatible for now... on the
   plus side, I haven't had to think about the upstart -> systemd
   transition at all otherwise.
2. The other is that Nautilus (now GNOME Files) doesn't seem to want to
   live in the launcher or the <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> switcher. It vanishes from both
   locations a few seconds after I open it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: 16.04 questions are off-topic until release.

Comment: Errors are off topic and should be reported against the package so a developer can check it and can fix it when needed. Should not even matter if it is Ubuntu+1, this goes for all Ubuntu releases. (there are exceptions of course :-) ). The problem with Nautilus: check if the .desktop file stays in the directory `~/.local/share/applications/` after you put it there yourself. I